# Can my employer detect that I am using a torrent client on my home pc while teleworking?

Tags: network, vpn, routing

I am working from home with a 'work' laptop, connected through a VPN client to my company and also to the customer networks.

I also have my 'home pc' on the same home network.

Both computers are connected to the same home router.

Can the customer or my work company detect that I am using a torrent client running on my home pc?

Comment: Since your proposed subnetwork design is a tangent to the question you asked, I've removed that part. However, everyone should set up "personal" and "work" subnetworks at home for all kinds of security reasons, so you should still do that regardless of the answer to the question. The answer is 'no', by the way.